# Can't make a post request in .NetCore RestApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

[image]

I have this model in `Meeting.cs`:

```
    public class Meeting
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public TimeSpan Start_time { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public TimeSpan End_time { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Url]
        public string Url { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"^[(a-zA-Z)' '(a-zA-Z)]*$",
         ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
        public string Owner { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression(@"^[(a-zA-Z)' '(a-zA-Z)]*$",
         ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
        public string Participant { get; set; }
    }
```

And it looks like this in `InitialMigration.cs`:

```
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "meetings",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                    Start_time = table.Column<TimeSpan>(type: "interval", nullable: false),
                    End_time = table.Column<TimeSpan>(type: "interval", nullable: false),
                    Date = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "timestamp without time zone", nullable: false),
                    Url = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: false),
                    Owner = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true),
                    Participant = table.Column<string>(type: "text", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_meetings", x => x.Id);
                });
        }
```

```
MeetingsController.cs
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.DataAccess;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Meetings")]
    public class MeetingsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IDataAccessProvider _dataAccessProvider;

        public MeetingsController(IDataAccessProvider dataAccessProvider)
        {
            _dataAccessProvider = dataAccessProvider;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Meeting> Get()
        {
            return _dataAccessProvider.GetMeetingRecords();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Meeting meet)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Guid obj = Guid.NewGuid();
                meet.Id = obj.ToString();
                _dataAccessProvider.AddMeetingRecord(meet);
                return Ok();
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public Meeting Details(string id)
        {
            return _dataAccessProvider.GetMeetingSingleRecord(id);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public IActionResult Edit([FromBody] Meeting meet)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _dataAccessProvider.UpdateMeetingRecord(meet);
                return Ok();
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public IActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {
            var data = _dataAccessProvider.GetMeetingSingleRecord(id);
            if (data == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            _dataAccessProvider.DeleteMeetingRecord(id);
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

How to fix this?

But my JSON data seems to be not valid, I don't understand why. Maybe something is wrong with `date`? In what format should I write time and date?

But my JSON data seems to be not valid, I don't understand why. Maybe something is wrong with `date`? In what format should I write time and date?

Comment: please show your controller action.

Comment: now I need to see _dataAccessProvider.AddMeetingRecord(meet);

Comment: @Sergey, `public void AddMeetingRecord(Meeting meet)
        {
            _context.meetings.Add(meet);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }`

Comment: Sorry but could you please post your input data from postman. I would like to test it.

Comment: ```{
    "date": "10/19/2021",
    "start_time": "19:23:23",
    "end_time": "20:23:23",
    "url": "https://blog.reedsy.com/writing-apps/#11__hemingway",
    "owner": "Michael KKK",
    "participant": "John PPP"
}```

Comment: @Sergey I found how to see errors, and I got error in Postman "the json value could not be converted to system.datetime", I googled and it appeared that I should write date like this 2019-01-06T17:16:40, but I don't like it how can I write it in format dd.mm.yyyy?

Comment: I am thinking now, since I run this in Postman and don't have any errors at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my test I couldn' find any errors at all but I tnink you have problem with the Date format. Try to add to your meeting class new property:

```
[NotMapped]
public string StrDate { get; set; }
```

and use this name for your string date:

```
{ "strdate": "10/19/2021", "start_time": "19:23:23","end_time": "20:23:23", "url": "https://blog.reedsy.com/writing-apps/#11__hemingway", "owner": "Michael KKK", "participant": "John PPP" }
```

Convert your data insight of your action:

```
         [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Meeting meet)
        {
        
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var arrDate = meet.StrDate.Split('/');
                Guid obj = Guid.NewGuid();
                meet.Date = new DateTime(year: Convert.ToInt32(arrDate[2]), month: Convert.ToInt32(arrDate[0]), day: Convert.ToInt32( arrDate[1]));
                meet.Id = obj.ToString();
                
                return Ok(meet);
            }
            return BadRequest();
        }
```

Comment: I got an error `Build failed. Use dotnet build to see the errors`, and after typing dotnet build I got this `error CS1061: 'Meeting' does not contain a definition for 'StrDate' and no accessible extension method 'StrDate' accepting a first argument of type 'Meeting' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\Мар?я\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2.csproj]`

Comment: @Aska Did you add public string StrDate { get; set; } to your Meeting class?

Comment: yes I added, but actually I changed `public class Meeting` to `public class Meeting : IValidatableObject` and added some validation for StrDate

Comment: ```public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            List<ValidationResult> results = new List<ValidationResult>();

            DateTime temp;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(StrDate, out temp) == false)
            {
                results.Add(new ValidationResult("Date is wrong", new[] { "Date" }));
            }return results;
        }```

Comment: Just don't forget to include [NotMapped] attribute

Comment: I didn't forget, I added it as well

Comment: You don't have to put validation rule for this. This is the problem that your default system datetime in a different format. The stringt is not mapped and you can select any format that you like or need. You can put  year, month and day in any other and use any separators between them. Just correct you convertation code in the beginning of the action if you need.